# How to go about fixing Semver-major dependency vulnerabilities

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm relatively new to NPM, and am wondering the best practice to go about fixing Semver-major vulnerabilities. I'm getting [image: this one] at the moment, and wanted to see the best/easiest way to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: You can learn a lot from `man npm audit`. For example what `npm audit fix --force` does. Unfortunately installing a new major version not only fixes bugs, but also often introduces breaking changes, so patching vulnerabilites very often does require significant manual work.

Comment: Questions asking for "best practice" typically fall outside of the scope of stack overflow. Best practice is a moving target, since it evolves over time as tools and ecosystems change. It's also highly subjective most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

react-scripts is very popular and widely used and these vulnerabilities are usually resolved quickly.  try updating to the latest version, apparently anything over 3.0 has fixed this.  `npm i react-scripts@latest`

edit to add issue:  https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6790